# Install latest nvidia drives on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

I'm trying to install the latest nvidia driver on Google Kubernetes engine.
I have followed the instructions given by Google to install drivers on Kubernetes engine : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus?hl=fr#installing_drivers

But the driver version that is installed is 410.104.
I need at least 418.67 version of nvidia drivers.
I was not able to find a way to upgrade the drivers.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Kubernetes 1.13 was released on [June 4th](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes) and now supports driver 418.67.

Comment: Thanks of your answer.
Do you know if there's already a deployment script for this driver version? Or if I have to update the driver myself on the vm instance and change the clusters instance template?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the right script to install the latest drivers on kubernetes engine.
I have found it on this repo :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators
So instead of applying the recommended command :

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/stable/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
```

I applied the following command

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/daemonset.yaml
```

And I finally got 418.67 drivers installed in my kubernetes containers.